# Why am i getting __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given?

Tags: python, django

I am working on a project and I am getting this following error:

traceback:

```
TypeError at /account/reset-password
__init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

imports:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from django.contrib.auth.views import PasswordResetView, PasswordResetDoneView
```

url:

```
url(r'^reset-password$', PasswordResetView, name='reset_password'),
```

I am new to django, so welcomed help . ty

Comment: `PasswordResetView.as_view()`??

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [**`PasswordResetView`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.PasswordResetView) is a class-based view, you should specify the URL as:

```
url(r'^reset-password$', PasswordResetView.as_view(), name='reset_password'),
```

You do not want to *create* a new `PasswordResetView` each time you pass to the view, you want to create a HTTP response. The reason why you get the error is because now you will create a `PasswordResetView` (so you will call the `__init__(..)` method of the `PasswordResetView` class. There is a mismatch between the parameters used by the view, and the constructor of the object, hence the error. Even if there was no mismatch, there would - luckily enough - still be an error, since the result would be a `PasswordResetView` object, which is *not* a subclass of a `HttpResponse`.